# SEO and instant filtering

Tags: javascript, seo, filtering

Hi
my web site provides instant filtering of articles via JavaScript.

Initially, 12 most fresh summaries for articles are displayed.

Summaries of ALL articles are putted into JavaScript cache-object (rendered by server in script tags).
When user click on tags, corresponding summaries for articles will be taken from JS cache-object and inserted into the page as HTML pieces.

Does it have some negative impact on how SEO-friendly my web site is.

The main problem is clear: only 12 "static" URL's are displayed and another will appear programmatically only on user interaction.

How to make the site SEO-friendly, keeping this nice filtering feature ?

When i will add a link "all articles" that will load separate page with all articles, will it solve the SEO problems ?

Answer (score 1):

The way to make this work for Search Engines, user who don't have JavaScript and also in your funky way is to write this feature in stages.

Stage 1: Get a working "Paged" version of this page working, so it shows 12 results and you can click on "next page" and "last page" and maybe even on various page numbers.

Stage 2: Implement the filter using a form-post and have it change the results shown in the page view.

Stage 3: Add JavaScript over the top of the working form and have it display the results the normal post would display. You can also replace the full-page-reload for paging with JavaScript safe in the knowledge that it all works without JavaScript.

Most people use an AJAX request rather than storing an ever-increasing list in a JavaScript array.

Answer (score 0):

Crawlers (or most of them) don't enable javascript while crawling. therefore, all javascript powered content won't be referenced. And your site will be considered smaller as it is by search engines. this will be penalizing for your pages.

Making a "directory" page can be a solution. But if you do so, search engines will send user to these static pages, and not through your javascript viewer homepage.

Anyway, I would not recommend to make a javascript-only viewable content:

- First it's not SEO friendly
- then it's not javascript-disabled
  friendly
- imposibillity to use history
  functions (back and next)
- middle click "open in a new
  tab/window" won't be working.
- Also you can't bookmark javascript
  generated content

so is your nice feature nice enough to lose the points mentionned above?

There are ways to conciliate your feature + all those points but that's far from easy to do.